# how to use SEGUE in ios xcode4.5 with navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am having two screens.
screen 1: with a `textfield` and a button
on button click it will push to screen 2
screen 2: only a label
should display content of textfield in screen 1

i am able to move from one screen to another.But i dont know how to pass data.
I have done this much using `storyboard`.

I am new to `ios` programming. These are my doubts
since i am having 2 `viewcontrollers`,should i create seperate `viewcontroller.m` and `.h` files for each `viewcontroller` i am having ?
how to connect a view controller to a `viewcontroller` `class` file
I am only familiar with java and now confused with `storyboard` and their relativity to the code. 
(sorry for any rubbish doubts,since i am new to this. please help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement -prepareForSegue:sender: method in the Screen 1 view Controller and you can pass the data like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:segue sender:(id)sender{
    Screen2VC *target = segue.destinationViewController;
    target.passedData = self.textField.text;
}
```

the Screen2VC must has a property named "passedData"(or anything else in place of name passedData) to hold the textField's value which will be displayed in the Screen 2

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/), you will get an answers for how to pass data between viewcontrollers and to set the class of viewcontroller.

And answer to your another question: you need to have different .h and .m files for every viewcontroller and if you need the same class then you can reuse the viewcontrollers.